# No module named 'prompt_toolkit.formatted_text'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am totally new to Jupyter Notebook.

Currently, I am using the notebook with R and it is working well.

Now, I tried to use it with Python and I receive the following error.

> [I 09:00:52.947 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5),
>   new random ports
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>   "main", mod_spec)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code,
>   run_globals)
>
> File
>   "/home/frey/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py",
>   line 15, in  from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
>
> File
>   "/home/frey/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/init.py",
>   line 2, in  from .connect import *
>
> File
>   "/home/frey/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py",
>   line 13, in  from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
>
> File "/home/frey/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/init.py",
>   line 55, in  from .terminal.embed import embed
>
> File
>   "/home/frey/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py",
>   line 16, in  from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import
>   TerminalInteractiveShell
>
> File
>   "/home/frey/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py",
>   line 20, in  from prompt_toolkit.formatted_text import PygmentsTokens
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prompt_toolkit.formatted_text'
>
> [W 09:00:55.956 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed [W
>   09:00:55.956 NotebookApp] Kernel 24117cd7-38e5-4978-8bda-d1b84f498051
>   died, removing from map.

Hopefully, someone can help me.

Answer (score 4):

> ipython` 7.0.1 has requirement prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0, but you'll have prompt-toolkit 1.0.15 which is incompatible
>
> https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_console/issues/158

Upgrading `prompt-toolkit` will fix the problem.

```
pip install --upgrade prompt-toolkit
```

Answer (score 1):

It's more stable to create a kernel with an Anaconda virtualenv.

Follow these steps.

1. Execute Anaconda prompt.
2. Type `conda create --name $ENVIRONMENT_NAME R -y`
3. Type `conda activate $ENVIRONMENT_NAME`
4. Type `python -m ipykernel install`
5. Type `ipython kernel install --user --name $ENVIRONMENT_NAME`

Then, you'll have a new jupyter kernel named 'R' with R installed.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I am very late to answer, but I was able to fix this error by upgrading both `ipython` *and* `prompt_toolkit`.

```
pip install -U ipython prompt_toolkit
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fixed in the way its say in Github:
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4079

- open Anaconda Prompt typing

  ```
  python -m ipykernel install --user
  ```

Answer (score 0):

First Select your environment name. In my case it was **"env"**.

[image: img]

Then install the jupyter notebook from there.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case on VSCode remote environment for WSL2 (Ubuntu 22.04), Windows 11, I was directed here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Failure-to-start-Kernel-due-to-Modules-not-installed

Then follow instructions but open a terminal, activate the Conda environment and execute the command.

Trying any of the following in a VSCode Jupyter cell did not work

```
! conda install --name pytorch prompt-toolkit --update-deps --force-reinstall
#! pip install -U ptyprocess ipykernel, pyzmq
#! pip install --upgrade prompt-toolkit
```

but doing

```
conda install --name pytorch prompt-toolkit --update-deps --force-reinstall
```

then go back to VSCode, shift-ctrl-p to set the Python interpreter, refresh it, set the interpreter to the one you want then set the kernel in the top right of VSCode.

Now this cell executed without the error

```
import os
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your environment variable `Path`!
In the system variable `Path` add the following line

> C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts